# database registers user correctly but no email is send out

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I creeate an app on android ,database registers user correctly but no email is send out  and app displays my error message "cant register user at the moment" don't know what i am doing wrong 
This is part of the php with the registry function

```
   //function to register and add user email and password to the database
   public function registerUser($name,$email,$password){
     if($this->verifyEmailExists($email,"email") == FALSE){
       //$data = [':name' => $name,':email' => $email,':password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),':date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
       //$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_android_users (name, email, password,date) VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :date)";
       //$stmt= $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
       //$stmt->execute($data);
       //$insertid = $this->db->conn_id->lastInsertId();
       $data = array('name' => $name,'email' => $email,'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),'login_type'=>"email",'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
       $this->db->trans_start();
       $this->db->insert('tbl_android_users', $data);
       $insertid = $this->db->insert_id();
       $this->db->trans_complete();
       //echo $insertid; die;
       if ($insertid){
         $this->status = "ok";
         $this->message = "User registered successfully, We sent a verification code to your email address, Click on the link to verify your email address.";
         $this->user = $this->getUpdatedUser($email);
       }else{
         $this->status = "error";
         $this->message = "Cant register user at the moment";
       }
     }else{
       $this->status = "error";
       $this->message = "Email or Phone already exists";
     }

   }
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `if block` check fails, as it will only work if `$insertid` is `true`. That also means `$insertid` dataType must be a `Boolean`.

I would suggest to put a breakpoint at this line:

```
$insertid = $this->db->insert_id();
```

and try to register a user. See what value the #insertid is. It must be either null or `false` as that is why the code is failing.

## EDIT

if your $insertid is `null`, then check in your repository if the following function returns anything or not:

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

It logically should returns either a `Boolean` or the datatype that it is trying to insert as its return.

Comment: yes you are right, id is null how can i fix this please,many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should close the transaction before accessing the InsertID property. First execute `$this->db->trans_complete();` before you try to get the insertID by using `$insertid = $this->db->insert_id();`